# Xcode Capabilities are needed?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, game-center, capability

I'm a beginner of ios development, and I wonder whether capabilities are needed.
For example, I can GameCenter in my project without turning on GameCenter in Capabilities.

My question is what will happen if I use GameCenter in my project without turning on GameCenter and submit it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html explains a bit. It just automatically provisions your project to support Game Center.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you try and write game center code, it will not authenticate the player because game center in the app settings is not on, and you cannot turn the game center app setting on until you have an apple developer account. Bottom line is, if game center is not enabled in the project, it will not authenticate the player and it will not work. With that said, you cannot submit it anyway without an apple developer account, and if you have one you can just turn it on.